# Extracting Math expressions from a string C++ PCRE

Tags: c++, regex

I need to extract expressions from string.

Input string

```
N100$VAR1=100+$Var2*30 + #29X=30.99Z=(#991+ ( 30*SIN(60) + $VAR32 ) / #32)
```

Output Expected

```
$VAR1=100+$Var2*30 + #29
X=30.99
Z=(#991+ ( 30*SIN(60) + $VAR32 ) / #32)
```

I tried with following

```
(\$*[A-Z][A-Z\d\_]+)\s*=\s*([\S]*)\s*([\+\-\/\*]\s*(\$*[A-Z0-9\.\_\)]+)\s*)
```

This is working when there are no white space in the string
I want it to work with white space also.

TIA.

Comment: Are you really interested in the capturing group values? Or can we discard them? It is easier to get a `$VAR1=100+$Var2*30 +#29` with 2 groups: `$VAR1` and `100+$Var2*30 +#29`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex that will match the variable up to the `=`, and then any text up to the first occurrence of the variable+`=` pattern:

```
(\$*[A-Z][A-Z\d_]*)\s*=\s*((?:(?![A-Z]\d+\.\d+|[A-Z][A-Z\d_]*\s*=).)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/86ws7Q/3)

**Details**:

- `(\$*[A-Z][A-Z\d_]*)`  - Group 1:

  - `\$*` - 0+ `$` symbols
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `[A-Z\d_]*` - 0+ uppercase ASCII letters, digits or `_`
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:(?![A-Z]\d+\.\d+|[A-Z][A-Z\d_]*\s*=).)*)` - Group 2:

  - `(?:(?![A-Z]\d+\.\d+|[A-Z][A-Z\d_]*\s*=).)*` - 0+ sequences of:

    - `(?![A-Z]\d+\.\d+)` - the next char cannot be the starting char of a sequence: uppercase ASCII letter, 1+ digits, `.` and 1+ digits
    - `(?![A-Z][A-Z\d_]*\s*=)` - the next char cannot be the starting char of a sequence: uppercase ASCII letter, 0+ uppercase ASCII letters/digits/`_`, 0+ whitespaces, `=`
    - `.` - a char other than line break chars

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/potjYp):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex r(R"((\$*[A-Z][A-Z\d_]*)\s*=\s*((?:(?![A-Z]\d+\.\d+|[A-Z][A-Z\d_]*\s*=).)*))");
    std::string s = "N100$VAR1=100+$Var2*30 + #29X=30.99Z=(#991+ ( 30*SIN(60) + $VAR32 ) / #32)";
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                             i != std::sregex_iterator();
                             ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << "Match value: " << m.str()      << '\n';
        std::cout << "    Capture: " << m[1].str()   << '\n';
        std::cout << "    Capture: " << m[2].str()   << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Match value: $VAR1=100+$Var2*30 + #29
    Capture: $VAR1
    Capture: 100+$Var2*30 + #29
Match value: X=30.99
    Capture: X
    Capture: 30.99
Match value: Z=(#991+ ( 30*SIN(60) + $VAR32 ) / #32)
    Capture: Z
    Capture: (#991+ ( 30*SIN(60) + $VAR32 ) / #32)
```

Comment: I have small issue. Actually I missed one more condition. My string can have `N100$VAR1=100+$Var2*30 + #29X=30.99Y100.3C234.12Z=(#991+ ( 30*SIN(60) + $VAR32 ) / #32)` should give `X=30.99` now this combines `X=30.99Y100.3C234.12`